# ETH Gas fee difference between sending to a wallet or a smart contract

Tags: ether, gas, smart-contract-wallets

I want to understand the difference of sending some ETH to a wallet of someone or to a smart contract. It seems costs are not the same. Is this correct?

If so, why does it probably cost more to send ETH to a smart contract than to another wallet?

Maybe someone has an idea or solution to reduce this gas fee for a smart contract receiver.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction's recipient is a contract the Ethereum's rules state its bytecode will be executed, so at least one opcode will be executed.

A contract compiled with solidity will make several checks to determine if it is a function call and dispatch it properly.

In order to accept ether payments a contract has to implement the [`receive`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) function (or the more general [`fallback`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/contracts.html#fallback-function) function).

For solc v0.8.3 the minimum contract compiled without optimizations uses 33 gas to receive ether.

```
contract Test {

    receive() external payable {
        /* Nothing to do here */
    }
}
```